# React-native-snap-carousel does not display image properly depending on the last index state

Tags: react-native, carousel

I am new to RC and I am facing an issue with react-native-snap-carousel. I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, View, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {

  const [useData1Bool, setUseData1Bool] = useState(true);

  const data1 = [
       {
         img: require("./assets/pic1.png"),
       },
       {
         img: require("./assets/pic2.png")
       }
     ];

  const data2 = [
       {
         img: require("./assets/pic3.png"),
       },
     ];

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const isCarousel = React.useRef(null);

  const data = useData1Bool ? data1 : data2;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <GestureHandlerRootView>
        <Carousel 
            layout={"default"}
            data={data}
            sliderWidth={100}
            itemWidth={100}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                  <Image 
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                    source={item.img}
                  />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              );
            }}
            onSnapToItem={(index) => setIndex(index)}
            ref={isCarousel}
        />
        <Text></Text>
        <Text></Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setUseData1Bool(true)}>
          <Text>Use data1 carousel</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <Text></Text>
        <Text></Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => setUseData1Bool(false)}>
          <Text>Use data2 carousel</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    mainView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});

package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "4.9.2",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0"
  }
}
```

This is available at: https://snack.expo.dev/@ndefeis/carousel?platform=android

I want to be able to switch between different sets of images (in this case, data1 and data2).

If I switch to data2 by clicking at the option "Use data2 carousel" after snapping to the image at data1[0], it works fine (image at data2[0] is displayed).

However, if I switch to data2 by clicking at the option "Use data2 carousel" after snapping to the image at data1[1], it does not work fine (image at data2[0] is NOT displayed). In this case, it seems that the correct image is there, but I need to click on it so that is displayed.

Please, what am I doing wrong ?

I want to be able to switch between different sets of images (in this case, data1 and data2).

If I switch to data2 by clicking at the option "Use data2 carousel" after snapping to the image at data1[0], it works fine (image at data2[0] is displayed).

However, if I switch to data2 by clicking at the option "Use data2 carousel" after snapping to the image at data1[1], it does not work fine (image at data2[0] is NOT displayed). In this case, it seems that the correct image is there, but I need to click on it so that is displayed.

Please, what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `second image`, it seems that there is no image that fits the `index` when the `data` is changed, so it is hidden.

The workaround is to initialize the index when the data is moved.

```js
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
          isCarousel.current.snapToItem(0,false) // <= add this
          setUseData1Bool(false)
        }}>
          <Text>Use data2 carousel</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```